# iOS 13 large title not visible until scroll

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

`UINavigationBar` is showing odd behaviour only when I present navigation controller on already presenting navigation controller. The large title does not visible until I scroll. It just shows empty space for large title. This is how I am setting up my navigation bar. Nothing fancy!

N.B. The below code is written in the subclass of navigation controller.

```
let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
appearance.backgroundColor = UIColor.appNavBarColor()
appearance.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 17.0),
        NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.white]
appearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.white]
navigationBar.standardAppearance = appearance
navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
```

This is how it shows up when presenting `UINavigationController`.

[image]